Dndkit how to force an item to remain in place in a vertical sortable list? (Also open to using other dnd libraries)
For example, suppose 5 was frozen. Then, if 4 was dragged below 6, the result of before and after would look like this:
before:

after:

Currently, I'm planning on using the margin between items, along with a position: absolute and manually calculated top and left to place frozen items into the desired location. However, this feels like a hacky solution and I'm looking for better ways to do it.
I am also open to using other dnd libraries.
